# How to get countryShortName, division, stateShortName, subLocality etc fields from Reverse Geo Coding from current location in Maps Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, reverse-geocoding

I am showing map in my application for current location. So, I am trying to get reverse geo coding from current location to get the data for current location details in MKMapView.

```
 func getAddressFromLatLon(coords: CLLocation) {
        let loc: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:coords.coordinate.latitude, longitude: coords.coordinate.longitude)

        let ceo: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()

        ceo.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler:
            {(placemarks, error) in
                if (error != nil)
                {
                    print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                }
                var placeMark: CLPlacemark!

                let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
                print(placemarks![0] as Any)
                placeMark = placemarks?[0]
                print(placeMark.addressDictionary! as Any)

                if pm.count > 0 {
                    let pm = placemarks![0]
//                    print(pm.country)
//                    print(pm.locality)
//                    print(pm.subLocality)
//                    print(pm.thoroughfare)
//                    print(pm.postalCode)
//                    print(pm.subThoroughfare)

                    var addressString : String = ""
                    if pm.subLocality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.subLocality! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.thoroughfare != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.thoroughfare! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.locality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.locality! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.country != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.country! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.postalCode != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.postalCode! + " "
                    }


                    print(addressString)
                    self.addressTextField.text = addressString
                    self.locationCommentsTextField.text = pm.thoroughfare

                }
        })

    }
```

But, its printing only following

```
Optional([AnyHashable("Street"): Infinite Loop, AnyHashable("ZIP"): 95014, AnyHashable("Country"): United States, AnyHashable("City"): Cupertino, AnyHashable("State"): CA, AnyHashable("Name"): Apple Inc., AnyHashable("SubAdministrativeArea"): Santa Clara, AnyHashable("Thoroughfare"): Infinite Loop, AnyHashable("FormattedAddressLines"): <__NSArrayM 0x60400204b040>(
Apple Inc.,
Infinite Loop,
Cupertino, CA  95014,
United States
)
, AnyHashable("CountryCode"): US])
```

> But, I want following fields as well, only few data I am able to
>   getting.
>
> City, comments, country, countryShortName, division, platform, region, resolvedAddress, state, stateShortName, street, streetNumber, subLocality, userAddress, zipCode

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found by Apple docs finally, most of the fields I got it.
This may be helpful someone in future.

```
func getAddressFromLatLon(coords: CLLocation) {
        let loc: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:coords.coordinate.latitude, longitude: coords.coordinate.longitude)

        let ceo: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()

        ceo.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler:
            {(placemarks, error) in
                if (error != nil)
                {
                    print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                }
                var placeMark: CLPlacemark!

                let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
                print(placemarks![0] as Any)
                placeMark = placemarks?[0]
                print(placeMark.addressDictionary! as Any)

                if pm.count > 0 {
                    let pm = placemarks![0]
                    var addressString : String = ""
                    if pm.subLocality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.subLocality! + ", "
                        self.reverseGeoCodeDic["subLocality"] = pm.subLocality //neighborhood, common name
                    }
                    if pm.thoroughfare != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.thoroughfare! + ", "
                        self.reverseGeoCodeDic["thoroughfare"] = pm.thoroughfare // street name
                    }
                    if pm.locality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.locality! + ", "
                        self.reverseGeoCodeDic["locality"] = pm.locality //// city
                    }
                    if pm.country != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.country! + ", "
                        self.reverseGeoCodeDic["country"] = pm.country //country
                    }
                    if pm.postalCode != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.postalCode! + " "
                        self.reverseGeoCodeDic["postalCode"] = pm.postalCode // zip/postal code
                    }
                    if pm.subLocality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.subLocality! + " "
                        self.reverseGeoCodeDic["subLocality"] = pm.subLocality // neighborhood
                    }
                    if pm.administrativeArea != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.subAdministrativeArea! + ", "
                        self.reverseGeoCodeDic["administrativeArea"] = pm.administrativeArea // state
                    }
                    if pm.subAdministrativeArea != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.subAdministrativeArea! + ", "
                        self.reverseGeoCodeDic["subAdministrativeArea"] = pm.subAdministrativeArea subAdministrativeArea // county
                    }

                    print(addressString)
                    print(self.reverseGeoCodeDic)
                    self.addressTextField.text = addressString
                    self.locationCommentsTextField.text = pm.thoroughfare

                }
        })

    }
```